# How to override PlatformTransactionManager correctly without affecting Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a batch process that extended `DefaultBatchConfigurer` as follows. Since I am using Spring Data JPA I need to override `PlatformTransactionManager` in `Process` class because otherwise respotiory save method will not work. So I need to know what is the best way to override `PlatformTransactionManager`? Is the following code is good or I have to set any other params in `JpaTransactionManager`? Because this is causing whole Spring Data Repositories not to work if I didn't override the `PlatformTransactionManager`.

```
public class Process extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    private @Autowired DataSource dt;

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpa = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpa.setDataSource(dt);
        return jpa;
    }
}
```

I have following parameters in `application.properties` file. If I override `PlatformTransactionManager` will the following work as expected?

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```